# Django Rest Framework: advanced queryset filtering based on another model

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am using Django Rest Framework as a backend for an app.

I have a `User` that has one `Wallet`. Then I have `Item`. If a `User` wants an `Item` it creates an instance in his/her `Wallet` called `WalletItem`. All works well.

Now I want to limit the number of items for the `User` using an attribute `limit_usage`.

First, I added a check to post method adding new instance that checks the number of item instances in `User`'s `Wallet`. So the user gets 403 when trying to add third `WalletItem` if `limit_usage == 2` for this `Item`.

I would like to override a `get_queryset()` method or `queryset` in `list()`/`retrieve()` methods so that if anonymous user calls `/items/` there are unfiltered items in response. However if the user is authenticated I would like to filter only those Items that s/he is allowed to put in the Wallet, i.e. those that have not exceeded limit_usage for current user.

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', related_name='wallet')

class Item(models.Model):
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField()
    valid_to = models.DateTimeField()
    limit_usage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

class WalletItem(models.Model):
    wallet = models.ForeignKey('Wallet', related_name='%(class)ss')
    offer = models.ForeignKey('Item', related_name='offer')

class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        time_now = now()
        self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(
            valid_from__lte=time_now,
            valid_to__gte=time_now,
        )
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I created a method of `Item` class that should have helped me but I realized I cannot use it in the queryset:

```
def is_visible_for_user(self, user=None):
    if not self.limit_usage or not user:
        return True
    ct = WalletItem.objects.filter(item=self, wallet=user.wallet).count()
    return self.limit_usage > ct
```

So I can iterate through the queryset to see if each item can be visible for the user, however I cannot construct the queryset out of this filtered list.
I found something similar here on SO: [Django REST Framework : filtering with another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105986/django-rest-framework-filtering-with-another-table) but the response did not help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You firstly need to check if user is authenticated, it not, then return every `Item`. Then to filter out `Item` objects if corresponding `WalletItem` objects exceeded its limit.

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Sum

...

class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_anonymous:
            return queryset

        queryset = queryset.annotate(user_wallet_items=Sum(
            Case(
                When(walletitem__wallet_id=user.wallet_id, then=1),
                default=0, output_field=IntegerField()
            )) \
            .filter(user_wallet_items__lte=F('limit_usage'))
        return queryset
```

I suggest you to move your filtration based on current time to the same `get_queryset()` method, since it's belong there.

Note: i've not tested this approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm. I only added `Q(limit_usage=0)` to cover the items that has no limit. Thanks to your reply I discovered whole new world of [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

Comment: @JurajBezručka you are welcome, I discovered the same while I was preparing to answer.:)